# Done some work during start animation . WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-animation

I am making a sartup animation screen in my wpf app . And i want to do some work during that animation . How to do this ? i want to do some sticky stuff in that time ? so that my app run faster after that animation .

how can i do this ?

Comment: You should look at `VisualStateManager`. It allows you to define a  states with entry and exit animations and an animation that plays while in the state. You can use a boolean to trigger the state. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/02/27/the-visualstatemanager-and-triggers.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about non-UI related "sticky stuff", like loading some data, you can off load the heavy work into a background thread, for example:

```
// Start playing loading animation (you can use visual state like Gusdor suggested)
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>
{
    // Do heavy work here.
}.ContinueWith(task => 
{
    // Stop loading animation here
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

If your heavy work involves UI activities, I recommend doing it right before stopping the loading animation in the `ContinueWith` block. Unfortunately, UI activities can only be done on the UI thread, so whatever you are doing in the `ContinueWith` block will cause some degree of UI pauses, regardless whether they are observable.